# Mapping internally

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, mapping-engine

Right now to test the web application on an external site, the web app was extended to a site that is mapped to an external IP address.

When the site goes live, on a different IP address, users will access the site from the url, and the internal firewall will route to the internal IP of my SharePoint server.

My question is, do I need to modify my mappings in anyway, or will redirecting the external user to my internal sharepoint IP be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be more worried about Bindings in IIS rather than Alternate Access Mappings, but even then IIS should take care of them perfectly fine - do you know what firewall is in use? ISA and TMG handled this perfectly OK but I think TMG is now out of support.

Comment: I'm not sure of the firewall. I think all that really needs to be done is when rerouting from the URL to the SharePoint server, that I include the port (ie. 10.10.10.10:3320) to the actual SharePoint web application. Does that sound like it makes sense?

Comment: I set up a staging site, to test. typing in the base url: www.staging.abcd.com gives me an unexpected error 'File Not Found' when it routes through the 'VariationRoot.aspx' page. However, if I go to the variation sites directly (ie. www.staging.abcd.com/en-us) the site works as expected. Any ideas as to why that is?